# Were Telomeres the Master Key to Abiogenesis

Tags: metabolism, abiogenesis, nucleotide-metabolism

Knowing as we do now that all manner of complex organic molecules and viscelles/micelles form spontaneously in various environments, from hot vents perfect for basic hydrophobic H-C fatty acids and stable charged H-C-O-P hydrophobics - to volcanic glass micro-chambers, clay-layer geometry and water ice fractal symetry,  that all combine to create ideal nanoscale everywhere rapid self assembly scenarios for various amino acids etc that in turn can form RNA like segments and combinations... I can't help but wonder what scenario is best situation pre-biotic that can form Telomeric sequences.

It seems to me, an instinctive feeling after viewing so many bioscience and life origin videos, that in all the random prebiotic assembly and disassembly of molecules, the perfection of replication lies in repetition that first needed a master start and stop sequence control, as master of other sub gene start stop codons.

Of course a myriad of biophysics factors come into play in origin theory and I am far from expert but I wonder if anyone can provide solid
references about abiogenisis and telomeres?

Tough question to word here, and too vast a topic when I try and narrow the web searches.  However, the amino squences for telomeres are finite I believe and so before life kept repeating itself what molecules in what environment crates the combination best?

Comment: When you refer to amino acids (twice) I assume that you mean nucleotides?

Comment: I believe that is correct Alan. Being uncertain I used the word amino sequence, although that might be ambigous.

Comment: This lecture discussing the crebs cycle, along  with a beautiful animation illustrating the natural harmony of sequential assembly and disassembly  of H C and O building blocks, maybe be more the answer to my phrase "Master Key"  https://youtu.be/0cwvj0XBKlE?t=41m16s

Answer (score 2):

No, they weren't. Interesting hypothesis though!

However, that hypothesis is missing a very important piece of information: prokaryotes don't typically have telomeres.

Because their DNA is typically circular, rather than linear, telomeres aren't necessary, and there is no shortening problem.

See the [Wikipedia page on telomeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomere) for more information. There are various theories on the origins of telomerases and telomere evolution, check out [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=telomere+evolution).